# how to clean relational data using powerquery

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerquery

I have two CSV, one of which references "ids" of the other.

This represents a collection of advices (first CSV) given by a specific user among a collection of users (second CSV)

The problem is that the advices csv contain a numbers identifying user which are NOT in the CSV.

I would like to ignore those advices referencing a invalid user id, and have the "cleaned" data in powerpivot.

Is it possible to do that in the powerquery / powerpivot / excel toolchain (other than with vlookup..) ?

Comment: actually there is a 'merge' button in the clickclick interface which allows to join. it is called merge and has the clickclick option to drop rows not found.

Comment: nicolas, can you share some sample data?